# How to use formative indicators in covariance-based SEM with lavaan?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm trying to build a covariance-based structural equation model (SEM) using both reflective and formative specifications of latent variables. I use the `sem` function in the `lavaan` package for estimation (`R` version 3.1.3, `lavaan` version 0.5-18). But estimates turn always out to be zero which is unreasonable.

The `lavaan` model syntax uses `=~` for reflective specification of latent variables, `<~` for formative specification of latent variables, and `~` for regressions (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lavaan/docs/model.syntax). Here is a simple working example with only reflective specifications. It is a simplified version of the example provided at http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/sem.html and by `example(sem)`:

```
library(lavaan)
model <- ' 
# latent variable definitions
ind60 =~ x1 + x2 
dem60 =~ y1 + y2
# regressions
dem60 ~ ind60
'
summary(sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy))
```

Now assume that based on prior theory I would know that dem60 is a formative construct composed of y1 and y2. Thus I change the specification from `=~` to `<~` and obtain the following code:

```
library(lavaan)
model <- ' 
# latent variable definitions
ind60 =~ x1 + x2 
dem60 <~ y1 + y2
# regressions
dem60 ~ ind60
'
summary(sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy))
```

The estimates for both y1 and y2 turn out to be zero. Analogously, the regression effect of ind60 on dem60 turns out to be zero. What do I need to change to get a meaningful result?

Several websites and blogs suggested the following modifications:

1. Fix one parameter in the formative construct, i.e. `dem60 <~ 1*y1 + y2`.
2. Allow for covariance of the manifest indicators, i.e. `y1 ~~ y2`.
3. Fix the variance of the formative construct, i.e. `dem60 ~~ 1`.
4. Free the variance of the formative construct, i.e. `dem60 ~~ NA*dem60`.

None of these are working. Again: What do I need to change to get a meaningful result?

Comment: The error term for `dem60` is not identified. Note if you switch the direction of `ind60` and `dem60` (and fix one of the parameters) the lavaan will spit out an estimate (i.e. `model <- 'ind60 =~ 1*x1 + x2 \n dem60 <~ 1*y1 + y2 \n ind60 ~ dem60'`). Although that model is still a Heywood case. If you add another manifest variable and fix the variance it appears to be identified (e.g. `model <- 'ind60 =~ 1*x1 + x2 + x3 \n dem60 <~ 1*y1 + y2 \n ind60 ~ dem60 \n ind60 ~~ 1*ind60'`).

Comment: More generally, you need some type of external information to identify the formative construct. If you don't have that information, you might as well just look at `y1 ~ ind60` and `y2 ~ ind60`.